# How to increase UICollectionViewCell height and show a label after button click in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Let say I have a `UICollectionViewCell` and below is my layout of the `cell`

```
LabelOne || LabelTwo || Button
```

In my `CollectionViewController`, I set cellForRowAtIndexPath = 30. Now, I want to show a label named labelThree under label two and increase my cell height = 60 after button pressed. Below is the layout what I want to accomplish after button press

```
LabelOne || LabelTwo || Button
Label Three
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Create custom cell using auto-layout and make sure to set the height of each label and button. Also make sure to set set the top and
>      bottom constraints for all components. This way, the cell will have
>      it's height.
> 2. At start, set the visibility of **Label Three** as hidden.
> 3. Set the visibility of **Label Three** as visible on button click.
> 4. Call **cell.layoutIfNeeded** just after that to reset the cell height.

Answer (score 0):

In cellForRow atIndexPath:

```
cell.updateConstraint = {
self.collectionView.beginUpdates()
self.collectionView.endUpdates()
}
```

In collectionview Cell:

```
var updateConstraint: () -> Void = {}
func addLabel() {
    // add three label
    // make cell new constraint
    self.updateConstraint()
}
```